# Obtaining circular toolpaths

Tags: c#, eyeshot

I generatig some toolpaths using Region.Pocket of Quickoffset methods. But, it returns as a linearpath collection in ICurve. The linearpath consists of only linear motions, does not have circular motions. So the circular ones should be detected from some point clusters. it is not locigal.

Is there any way to obtain circles or arcs from linearpath object? Or convert them to linear and circular ones.

Fatih.

Comment: This question is hard to answer, as there are a lot of important details missing. Try to put yourself in the shoes of those who know nothing about your problem. Make sure to [edit] your question to include all relevant content. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of point and want curves between them vice straight lines this could do the trick.

```
        LinearPath myLinearPath = new LinearPath();
        Curve curvePath = Curve.LocalInterpolation(myLinearPath.Vertices, true);
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your answer. But im tying to convert the linearpath to gcodes. So, G2, and G3 circular movements is needed. There is so much vertices in linearpath. Im trying to convert them only lines, arcs circles. The curve representation contains a lot of control points, and gcode generation is be so complex.